# Oracle 19C connectivity issue using VC++

Tags: visual-c++, oracle19c

Issue:  We are working on Oracle migration project from Oracle 11g to Oracle 19c. Please note, Visual Studio Professional 2015 version (VC++ code) is used here to generate the EDI files. We normally generate the EDI files through an Windows based EDI Service which is built using VC++ code.

Problem:-

We can connect the newly created database server from PowerBuilder ,Toad and SQLPLUS. However, with the same credentials when we create an EDI service and run, it fails to connect with the database. Getting following error - "ORA -1017: Invalid username/Password, logon denied". From code we checked and found, via OLOG connection is failing.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqvbK.png)

Please note: We have implemented the same set up in a different set of servers (Same config – Windows 2019, MS Visual Studio 2015 and Oracle 19c) and we are able connect without any issues. But this issue is happening when we try to do the same on another set of servers.

Solutions Explored till now:

1. Password reset.  Though we are able to connect to the DB through Powerbuilder, TOAD, SQL+ using the same password, we still tried to reset the password.
2. We are able to connect through the Microsoft Visual Studio -> Test Connection option with the same user name / password
3. TNS Name file validation
4. Added below parameters in the SQLNET.ORA file
   SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_CLIENT = 8
   SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_SERVER = 12

We need assistance/suggestions in resolving this issue.